# how to uninstall ng-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: angular11, ng-multiselect-dropdown

How to uninstall `ng-multiselect-dropdown`? I tried with `npm uninstall ng-multiselect-dropdown`, but it did not uninstalled.

`ng remove ng-multiselect-dropdown` also not working.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "_from": "ng-multiselect-dropdown",
  "_id": "ng-multiselect-dropdown@0.3.4",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha512-ZUzA4apGY7Y0MW7scF35iPYy4/DpIRhZcQiTICDJFs66+JoJOE+YqA+Tx9C2Ylv0B8tADX7PAsTQL9Jys1vWiQ==",
  "_location": "/ng-multiselect-dropdown",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "tag",
    "registry": true,
    "raw": "ng-multiselect-dropdown",
    "name": "ng-multiselect-dropdown",
    "escapedName": "ng-multiselect-dropdown",
    "rawSpec": "",
    "saveSpec": null,
    "fetchSpec": "latest"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#USER",
    "/"
  ],

  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nileshpatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/issues"
  },
  "bundleDependencies": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^1.9.0"
  },
  "deprecated": false,
  "description": "Angular Multi-Select Dropdown",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.802.2",
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~12.7.2",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.6.0-rc.2",
    "angular2-markdown": "^2.2.3",
    "codelyzer": "~5.1.0",
    "copyfiles": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^7.1.1",
    "karma": "~4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.11",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.5.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.19.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },
  "es2015_ivy_ngcc": "__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ng-multiselect-dropdown.js",
  "es2015": "fesm2015/ng-multiselect-dropdown.js",
  "esm2015": "esm2015/ng-multiselect-dropdown.js",
  "esm5": "esm5/ng-multiselect-dropdown.js",
  "fesm2015_ivy_ngcc": "__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ng-multiselect-dropdown.js",
  "fesm2015": "fesm2015/ng-multiselect-dropdown.js",
  "fesm5": "fesm5/ng-multiselect-dropdown.js",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/nileshpatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown#readme",
  "keywords": [
    "angular4",
    "angular8",
    "angular multiselect dropdown",
    "angular4 multiselect dropdown",
    "angular8 multiselect dropdown",
    "ng multiselect dropdown",
    "ng4 multiselect dropdown",
    "ng8 multiselect dropdown"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "bundles/ng-multiselect-dropdown.umd.js",
  "metadata": "ng-multiselect-dropdown.metadata.json",
  "module": "fesm5/ng-multiselect-dropdown.js",
  "name": "ng-multiselect-dropdown",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": ">=2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": ">=2.0.0"
  },
  "private": false,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/nileshpatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown.git"
  },
  "sideEffects": false,
  "typings": "ng-multiselect-dropdown.d.ts",
  "version": "0.3.4",
  "__processed_by_ivy_ngcc__": {
    "es2015": "11.0.9",
    "esm2015": "11.0.9",
    "esm5": "11.0.9",
    "fesm2015": "11.0.9",
    "fesm5": "11.0.9",
    "main": "11.0.9",
    "module": "11.0.9",
    "typings": "11.0.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublishOnly": "node --eval \"console.error('ERROR: Trying to publish a package that has been compiled by NGCC. This is not allowed.\\nPlease delete and rebuild the package, without compiling with NGCC, before attempting to publish.\\nNote that NGCC may have been run by importing this package into another project that is being built with Ivy enabled.\\n')\" && exit 1"
  }
}
```

could anyone help me?

Comment: Make sure that the ng-multiselect-dropdown package is not used in the project. Npm uninstall does not remove packages if they are referred. Also, you can try with npm prune, which probably would not work but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

try
npm uninstall ng-multiselect-dropdown